# Fetching core data from database fails due to FOR loop

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to retrieve all values excluding `null` from one attribute from my core data during the start of the `viewController`. But during the `for` loop the `no` always fetches value 0 and doesn't increment ahead. So my `results.count` is 8, then it displays 0 for 8 times and fetching the same value for the attribute.

```
func searchMark() -> Int
{
    do
    {
        let mngdCntxt = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AddedBookmark")
        let results = try mngdCntxt.fetch(fetchRequest)
        //fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        for no in 0..<results.count{

          if let match = results[no] as? AddedBookmark
             {
                  print(no)
                  let providerNo = match.value(forKey: "providerNo") as! Int
                  print("providerNo: \(providerNo)")
                  return providerNo
           } 
    }
    catch{}
    return 0
}
```

The value of `providerNo` is fetched same through the `for` loop.

Comment: That cannot be your real code, the parentheses do not match. Also that code would crash when `no` reaches the value `results.count`.

Comment: Instead of a (ugly index-based) for loop use a predicate to filter the items. And if the request is going to fetch an unique entity you will get always a non-optional array of that entity type. The optional downcast is nonsense.

Comment: @MartinR don't know, but it worked for the first row of db only

Comment: @MartinR On your experience and suggestion, I edited the loop. Hope now the code feels legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are

> trying to retrieve all values excluding `null` from one attribute

that implies that you actually want to return an `Int` **array** and your force-unwrapped attribute implies that the attribute is declared as non-optional. According to these two assumptions `null` is meant to be `0`

The logical conclusion is to specify a predicate to return all records whose `providerNo != 0`, map the items to the `providerNo` values and return that.

```
func searchMark() -> [Int]
{
    do {
        let mngdCntxt = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AddedBookmark")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "providerNo != 0")
        let results = try mngdCntxt.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [AddedBookmark]
        return results.map{ Int($0.providerNo) }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
        return [Int]()
    }
}
```

Comment: your code throws an error at line `return results.map{ $0.providerNo }` , error:- `Cannot convert value of type '@lvalue Int32' to closure result type 'Int'`

Comment: In Swift different numeric types are not interchangeable. Either change both occurrences of `[Int]` to `[Int32]` or create an `Int` in the closure `return results.map{ Int($0.providerNo) }`

Comment: I would like to ask a question before I accept this as answer. 1) I wanted to return Int one by one, what made you think an array of Int should be returned

Comment: Because the code in your question does return only **one** `Int` and the purpose of the loop is unclear.

Comment: Actually I was sending the `providerNo`(one by one) to other function to check whether the row is present in database and carry further task(in Table).

Comment: In this case you could return a `Bool`, specify a predicate to fetch records with that particular number by passing an parameter and check if the returned array `isEmpty`

Answer (score 1):

You return too soon, so the loop does not even increment once (and that is also why the loop does not crash when `no == results.count`):

```
func searchMark() -> Int {
    var output = 0
    do {
        let mngdCntxt = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AddedBookmark")
        let results = try mngdCntxt.fetch(fetchRequest)

        for no in 0...(results.count-1) {
           if let match = results[no] as? AddedBookmark {
                print(no)
                let providerNo = match.value(forKey: "providerNo") as! Int
                print("providerNo: \(providerNo)")
                output = providerNo
           }
        } 
        return output
    }
    catch{}
    return output
}
```

This function may not be exactly what you expect but it shows you how big the loop should be and when to return

Comment: works fine as expected, except didn't handle the null situation. I am trying to find a way to handle null here now